# Django simple model method error (unsupported operand type(s))

Tags: django, python-3.x, methods, admin

Hi I'm trying a simple thing, very documented, working in shell but not working in django admin.

my model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    loan_start = models.DateField()
    loan_ends = models.DateField()

    def loan_length(self):
        temp1 = self.loan_start
        temp2 = self.loan_ends
        res = temp2-temp1
        return res.days
```

my admin:

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'loan_start’, ‘loan_length’, ‘loan_ends’)
```

If I try this method in django shell works perfect:

```
manage.py shell

from books.models import *
```

grab some book:

```
somebook = Book.objects.get(id=19)

somebook.loan_start

Out[12]: datetime.date(2016, 4, 28)

somebook.loan_ends

Out[13]: datetime.date(2016, 8, 1)

somebook.loan_length()

Out[3]: 95
```

But if I try to use it in admin I get this error:

```
Exception Value: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.date'
```

I'm subtracting one date to another, getting a timedelta and returning it. I really don't know why the exception error.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like either `load_start` or `loan_ends` has a null value in the database. You either need to account for this scenario, or fix the data issue.

Comment: Hi karthikr, you'r right, there were one null value in the database. Thanks for the help.